# How can I improve the performance of this CopyTo method?

Tags: c#, performance, io

EDIT: I have now solved this. My answer posted below and will mark as solved when SO lets me.

I have a CopyTo (and a CopyToAsync) method to copy files in my C# application.
I have found that it is actually quite slow to copy the files, compared to something like Xcopy.

I extracted the core functionality of the copy method and placed it into a test console app to get the speed that it operates at versus Xcopy, and found the results actually quite different.

The results I get are:

Async Method: 36.59 seconds - Average speed: 1512.63 mb/sec

Sync Method: 36.49 seconds - Average speed: 1516.72 mb/sec

XCOPY: 5.62 seconds - Average speed: 9842.11 mb/sec

All three of these used the exact same file, and the exact same destination.

StreamExtensions class:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
    {

        const int DEFAULT_BUFFER = 0x1000; // 4096 bits

        public static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, IProgress<long> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, int bufferSize = DEFAULT_BUFFER)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            long totalRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
            {
                await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken);

                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                totalRead += bytesRead;
                progress.Report(totalRead);
            }
        }

        public static void CopyTo(this Stream source, Stream destination, IProgress<long> progress, int bufferSize = DEFAULT_BUFFER)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            long totalRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                totalRead += bytesRead;
                progress.Report(totalRead);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `IProgress<long>` object is to report the file progress back to the calling method.

Example call implementation:

```
// Asynchronous version
public static async Task CopyFileSetAsync(Dictionary<string, string> fileSet)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < fileSet.Count; x++)
    {
        var item = fileSet.ElementAt(x);
        var from = item.Key;
        var to = item.Value;

        int currentProgress = 0;

        long fileSize = new FileInfo(from).Length;

        IProgress<long> progress = new SynchronousProgress<long>(value =>
        {
            decimal fileProg = (decimal)(value * 100) / fileSize;

            if (fileProg != currentProgress)
            {
                currentProgress = (int)fileProg;
                OnUpdateFileProgress(null, new FileProgressEventArgs(fileProg));
            }
        });

        using (var outStream = new FileStream(to, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (var inStream = new FileStream(from, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                await inStream.CopyToAsync(outStream, progress);
            }
        }

        OnUpdateFileProgress(null, new FileProgressEventArgs(100)); // Probably redundant
    }
}

// Synchronous version
public static void CopyFileSet(Dictionary<string, string> fileSet)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < fileSet.Count; x++)
    {
        var item = fileSet.ElementAt(x);
        var from = item.Key;
        var to = item.Value;

        int currentProgress = 0;

        long fileSize = new FileInfo(from).Length;

        IProgress<long> progress = new SynchronousProgress<long>(value =>
        {
            decimal fileProg = (decimal)(value * 100) / fileSize;

            if (fileProg != currentProgress)
            {
                currentProgress = (int)fileProg;
                OnUpdateFileProgress(null, new FileProgressEventArgs(fileProg));
            }
        });

        using (var outStream = new FileStream(to, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (var inStream = new FileStream(from, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                inStream.CopyTo(outStream, progress, 1024);
            }
        }

        OnUpdateFileProgress(null, new FileProgressEventArgs(100)); // Probably redundant
    }
}
```

Is there something that's preventing this from running as fast as it could? I'm just stumped as to how much slower it is compared to copy.

EDIT: Fixed a typo where I forgot a single ` around IProgress

Comment: Does altering the buffer size have a noticeable impact on the time taken?

Comment: `DEFAULT_BUFFER = 0x1000; // 4096 bits`. They are **bytes**, not **bits**.

Comment: `xcopy` uses the same underlying code as `robocopy` and probably copies files in parallel.

Comment: As suggested by Tom, try increasing the buffer size to 1024 * 1024 (1mb)

Comment: I've set the buffer size to a few different values in my actual application, but not the test project. None of the values made any noticeable difference. Values tried: 1024, 512 and 8192

Comment: @xanatos That's my bad, thanks. Misunderstood that at some point along the line. Most of this code was just straight copied over

Comment: What about something like 64K buffer? Also have you tried the official `FileStream.CopyTo` as that probably avoids a double copy?

Comment: Does the official ```FileStream.CopyTo``` have progress reporting? That is a must in this application

Comment: Well `xcopy` only gives you a list of the files it copied. It doesn't report the progress of each file. It may not even be reporting the files in the exact order they are completed for that matter. I think it also uses some very low level Win32 API's that share a ring of buffers.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to solve this by increasing the buffer to 1mb at the suggestion of Tom and xanatos. The speeds of all 3 are now comparable to each other

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14722232/tom) and [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos), I answered my own question:

I misunderstood the impact of buffer size. I had only gone so far as 8192 bytes as the buffer size. After taking on their suggestions, I increased the buffer size to 1mb (1048576 bytes), and this made a massive difference to the performance.

Async Method: 5.57 seconds - Average speed: 9938.68 mb/sec

Sync Method: 5.52 seconds - Average speed: 10028.36 mb/sec

XCOPY: 5.03 seconds - Average speed: 11007.84 mb/sec

Comment: What were the peak/average memory/CPU usage of each of those processes?

Comment: You might consider moving the buffer size down until you see a deleterious difference (I'm guessing using a 64 kbyte buffer might be nearly as fast).If you can get it under 85k, then you stay out of the large object heap

Comment: I think you mean 1MB not 1mb.

Comment: @ jwdonahue - During all 3, did not raise above 30% CPU util. Prior to that, was idling between 26-30%

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57. I'll look into reducing the buffer size until I see a noticeable drop in performance.